# Can't install Ros2 on Ubuntu 16.04 from debs

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I've been trying to follow the [tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Linux-Install-Debians/) for installing ROS2 Crystal from debs. However when I try doing apt install ros-crystal-desktop I get an error:

> E: Unable to locate package ros-crystal-desktop

When doing "sudo apt update" I can see:

> Hit:22 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Also the file vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list exists and has the following contents:

> deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu xenial main

I'm on a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 with 64 bit processor and I have ROS Kinetic installed and working flawlessly. Am I missing anything obvious here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311808/can%27t-install-ros2-on-ubuntu-16.04-from-debs/) by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2019-01-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Am I mussing anything obvious here?

Perhaps this comment from the page you link:

> Debian packages for ROS 2 Bouncy (the latest release) are available for Ubuntu Bionic; **packages for ROS 2 Ardent are available for Ubuntu Xenial**.

There are no `.deb`s for Ubuntu Xenial, no matter the architecture.

See also [REP-2000: ROS 2.0 Target Platforms - Crystal Clemmys (December 2018 - December 2019)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#crystal-clemmys-december-2018-december-2019), where Ubuntu Xenial is marked with an `[s]`, meaning:

> " [s] " Compilation from source, the ROS buildfarm will not produce any binary packages for these platforms.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) on 2019-01-02**:
OK, that was pretty obvious thing that I've missed. Thanks!

**Comment by [Tejas Kumar shastha](https://answers.ros.org/users/34361/tejas-kumar-shastha/) on 2019-08-19**:
Okay this is pretty misleading because the Tutorial page mentioned by OP wrongly mentions (as of posting this comment) that binaries of Crystal are indeed available for Xenial as well as Bionic!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-19**:
Can you clarify where you read that?

I only see:

> Debian packages for ROS 2 Crystal (the latest release) and ROS 2 Bouncy are available for Ubuntu Bionic; packages for ROS 2 Ardent are available for Ubuntu Xenial.

and:

> ROS 2 Ardent (Ubuntu Xenial)

**Comment by [Tejas Kumar shastha](https://answers.ros.org/users/34361/tejas-kumar-shastha/) on 2019-10-16**:
Terribly sorry for the late response, but I hope this is still relevant :
In the page https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/ , it says -

Binary packages¶

We provide ROS 2 binary packages for the following platforms:

```
Linux (Ubuntu Xenial(16.04) and Ubuntu Bionic(18.04))

    Debian packages

    "fat" archive

OS X

Windows
```